# Sorting array upon two criteria

Tags: javascript

Here's a data sample:

```
    Name          Code
1.  JOHNY          AG
2.  JOHNA          AJOH
3.  JOHN           BPO
4.  JAHN           JOH
```

What I want is to sort it according to the following criteria, given a search string:

```
  I. Name starts with that string
 II. Code includes that string
III. If there is a tie, initial order should be kept
```

For example,

```
"JOH" should return: 2 1 3 4 whereas "J" should return: 2 4 1 3
```

I have tried that but with no luck...

```
myArray.sort(function compare(firstElem) {   
      if (firstElem.name.startsWith(text)) 
        return -1;
      if (firstElem.code.includes(text)) 
        return -1;
      return 0;
   })
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve]

Comment: None of the search results here on SO have a solution? -> ["javascript array sort multiple"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+array+sort+multiple+critera+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will probably do what you want:

```js
const data=[["JOHNY","AG"],["JOHNA","AJOH"],["JOHN","BPO"],["JAHN","JOH"]];

function lookFor(t){
  return (a,b)=> (   +!b[0].indexOf(t)   -!a[0].indexOf(t) )
             ||  ( +!!~b[1].indexOf(t) -!!~a[1].indexOf(t) ) ;
}

console.log(data.sort(lookFor('JOH')));
console.log(data.sort(lookFor('J')));
```

In the function `lookFor()` there are potentially two tests to be performed:

1. `+!b[0].indexOf(t)` will return `1` if the string in `b[0]` (the "name") starts with  the contents of `t` and `0` if it starts differently. The same test will be proformed with `a[0]`. Only when the difference between those two results is `==0` the second condition will be tested.
2. The term `+!!~b[1].indexOf(t)` checks whether `b[1]` *starts* with the contents of `t` (= 1) or not (= 0).